# .Find method not searching in order

Tags: excel, vba

**Can anyone explain why the string in `D2` is being built out of order in the first loop?**

This is only happening for the first search value, `Dom`. The rest of the strings are being built in the order in which they appear (see `Column B`). I treid adding `SearchDirection:= xlNext` but the output remained the same *with* or *without* that bit of code.

In the photo, `Column A:B` are the raw data and `Column C:D` are the output from macro.

The cell in question is `D2`. It should show `USD/EUR/GBP` instead of `EUR/GBP/USD`

[image]

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim FoundName As Range, SearchRange As Range, Names As Range, Name As Range
Dim MyString As String, i As Long

ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("C1"), Unique:=True

Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set Names = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Name In Names
    Set FoundName = SearchRange.Find(Name, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, Name)
            MyString = MyString & FoundName.Offset(, 1) & "/"
            Set FoundName = SearchRange.FindNext(FoundName)
        Next i
    Name.Offset(, 1) = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 1)
    MyString = ""
Next Name
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the search range to `Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`. I think I remember reading somewhere that `Find` starts **after** the first cell in the range, so technically it starts searching **in** the _second_ cell.

Comment: @Mistella I have not tried that. Makes perfect sense. Can test in an hour or so -

Comment: Very good Mistella and urdearboy. I usually use something like the following and it works all the time: `Set SearchRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:="whatever you want", After:=ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True) `  and  `Set SearchRange = ws.Cells.FindNext(After:=SearchRange)`

Comment: @Guest this was a solution I was working on for someone else and it ended up being a good one for practice since I realized this code systematically removes the possibility of the find method being nothing (which I is why there is no check that is usually associated with .Find)

Comment: @urdearboy, I hear you. I like it. I personnaly use a Do-While loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245196/vba-userform-as-inputbox/51246398#51246398 for example)

Comment: @pnuts I have not thanks for sharing! Will adjust in future posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) about the `Range.Find` method, the *After* parameter is:

> The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that *After* must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. **If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range**.

(Emphasis mine)

---

In your code, you set the range you're searching like:

```
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

which means that the first cell *actually* searched will be `Range("A3")`. There are two ways of fixing this:

1. Expand the search range to include "A1", so the default start is "A2"
2. Specify the *After* parameter as the last cell in the range. Since the search wraps back around to the first cell after reaching the last cell.

---

In your scenario, I believe the simplest solution would be (1). This can be done by simply adjusting your code line to read:

```
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: The simplest solutions are always the best. +1 for doing my research for me lol i way over complicated this in my troubleshooting efforts