# VBA Loop in Word to find wildcard strings misses first occurrence

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, find

I have some VBA for Microsoft Word that is supposed to find some five digit numbers using wildcards in multiple files and then the sticks them and the path/file into an excel file. Unfortunately, it ALWAYS misses the first occurrence of the wildcard string. **I cannot determine why!**

I've tried reordering things to make sure that it's not being missed, however, I am unable to get it working properly. When I run the wildcard search myself by hand, it finds the first occurence. It doesn't do it in VBA, however.

```
Public Sub TestFindNumbers()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 2 ' Row in Excel to start

    Dim ObjExcel As Object, ObjWorkBook As Object, ObjWorksheet As Object

    Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")

    Set ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set ObjWorksheet = ObjWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    Set dlgFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With dlgFile
        dlgFile.AllowMultiSelect = True
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For nDocx = 1 To dlgFile.SelectedItems.Count


                Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
                Set objDocx = ActiveDocument

                With objDocx.Range
                    With .Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                        .Text = "[0-9]{5}"
                        .Replacement.Text = ""
                        .Forward = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindStop
                        .Format = False
                        .MatchWildcards = True
                        .Execute
                    End With

                    Do While .Find.Found
                        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd

                        .Find.Execute

                        If .Text <> "" Then
                            ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) = Left(.Text, 8)
                            ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 2) = dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
                        Else
                            i = i - 1
                        End If
                            i = i + 1



                    Loop
                End With


                objDocx.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
            Next nDocx
        Else
            MsgBox ("You need to select documents first!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ObjWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Number"
    ObjWorksheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Path & Filename"



    ObjExcel.Visible = 1



    Set objDocx = Nothing
    Set ObjExcel = Nothing
    Set ObjWorkBook = Nothing
    Set ObjWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

I created a single test file with the following:

```
1234 Shouldn’t be selected
12345 Select this one. First occurrence.
98765 Another good one
568 Nope
This one is 55555 in the middle
End
```

When I run my VBA code, I'm getting 98765 and 55555 as hits. Unfortunately, 12345 isn't being found.

Comment: If the first occurrence is also the cell the `.Find` is starting on, and the `.Find` is not looping back to the beginning, you may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450023/9259306) I wrote for a different question with a potentially similar issue.

Comment: @Mistella. Thank you. I tried changing the .Wrap to wdFindContinue, but it just seems to get stuck in a loop. Interestingly enough, though, it returns the first occurrence last before looping. I still cannot make sense as to why it would be happening. Isn't position in the document irrelevant when using Range (as oppose to Selection)?

Comment: The default start of the `.Find` search is positionally dependent. If you read the section I quoted in the answer I linked to, Microsoft states that, by default, the search starts _**after the cell in the upper-left corner**_ of the specified range.

Comment: I found the documentation for the [Word `.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code in the question is not finding the search terms as expected:

The `Collapse`, then `Find.Execute` methods are in the loop before the first result is picked up. Since `.Execute` is also in the `With` block preceding the loop, `Find` runs twice, thus masking the first occurrence of the search term.

In addition:

1) Preferably, a specific `Range` should be used for the search, rather than the entire document (`objDocx.Range`). This is due to the "collapsing" - it works more reliably when there's a specific `Range` object.

2) Do *not* use `Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue` as suggested in comments. `wdFindStop` (as in the code in the question) is correct when using `Find` in a loop. `wdFindContinue` will often lead to an "infinite loop" as Word will start at the beginning of the document again, and again...

3) It's possible (better) to set a `Document` object when a file is being opened (or created), rather than relying on `ActiveDocument` in a second step:

```
 Set objDocx =  Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
```

Here's the part of the code that has to do with the Find - I've left out the Excel parts to make it easier to read

```
Dim objDocx As Word.Document
Dim rngFind As Word.Range

Set objDocx = Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
Set rngFind = objDocx.content

With rngFind
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[0-9]{5}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With

    Do While .Find.Found
         If .Text <> "" Then
             ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) = Left(.Text, 8)
             ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 2) = dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
         Else
             i = i - 1
         End If
         i = i + 1

        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Do While loop. Change it to:

```
            Do While .Find.Found
                ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) = Left(.Text, 8)
                ObjWorksheet.Cells(i, 2) = objDocx.Name
                i = i + 1
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                .Find.Execute
            Loop
```

Also, instead of:

```
        Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
        Set objDocx = ActiveDocument
```

use:

```
        Set objDocx = Documents.Open(dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx))
```